# Swift - Xcode - App slows down iPhone when it is in background

Tags: ios, performance, swift2

I have a performance issue with my app using `UIKit`. Every time I put my app in background and I open the multitask on an iPhone the scrolling gets very slow. In other words the app slows down the iPhone Performance. In xCode Debug Navigator it says that CPU impact is 0%. Why Is this happening and how can I debug this problem?

[image]